# windows could not start the MySQL. service on local computer. Error 2 : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am not able to start the MySQL server on my Windows system. When I tried in services.msc to run, I got this error:

[image: Screenshot]

Starting it through the XAMPP control panel does not work either:

[image: Screenshot]

Can you help me to solve this?

Comment: Your error message in the second link explains why your service is not able to start. Fix your path or try to reinstall the whole thing...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624234/how-to-change-the-path-of-mysql-services .. Go with this question answer.

Comment: I tried reinstalling whole. But could not run MYsql.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open windows services (Start->run ->Services.MSC)
2. Find service with name "Mysql Server" and check path, it should be something like that:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Databases\MySQL51\bin\mysqld.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Databases\MySQL\Data\my.ini" MySQL

3. Make sure that Mysql folder and executable file mentioned above exist by this path.

OR

Sometimes the file name of mysqld-nt.exe renamed to mysqld-nt.exe~ so rename it back to its original name and this may solve the problem.

Comment: I found path C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5 here MySQL Server 5.5 folder didn't exist at all...

Comment: change the default path of mysql server in xamp my.ini

Comment: Its not only the path. But ports also were conflicting. I resolved. Thank-you....

Comment: Thanks for this answer very very much. It helped me see that the path to MySQL service executable does not exist. I wonder why so but I will just uninstall the MySQL service and re-initialize the data directory with the --base-dir=path option set and re-install the service That should solve my case. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the path: C:Programs Files\MariaDB 10.2\data..
2. Lookout for my.ini file. Open the file and check the path for "datadir".
3. If that does not match to your installed directory then update it.
4. Your problem will be solved for sure.

Comment: The path was C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0 on my computer instead, but the fix worked so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and solved it.

Just modify the registry editor value.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services/MySQL/ImagePath
```

[image]