# Unable to start the MySQL80 service on local computer

Tags: mysql

I'm installing the MySQL8.0.18. While applying the configuration, whenever I press the execute it stops on `starting the server` and does not configure it. In the log tab, it says;

```
Beginning configuration step: Starting the server
Attempting to start service MySQL80...
Failed to start service MySQL80.
Waiting until a connection to MySQL Server 8.0.18 can be established (with a maximum of 10 attempts)...
Retry 1: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...    
Retry 2: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 3: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 4: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 5: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 6: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 7: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 8: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 9: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Waiting 5 seconds before the next connection attempt...
Retry 10: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with no password...
MySQL error 1042: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
Failed to connect to MySQL Server 8.0.18 after 10 attempts.
Ended configuration step: Starting the server
```

I don't know if its the location error or something because I saved my setup in `E:\setups\mySQL\setup`. It gives the error shown in the snapshot.
I tried to solve it according to [the first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970454/mysql-configuration-stops-at-starting-server/29243268#29243268) but it doesn't seem to help.

[image: cannot find the file]

I tried to reinstall it but it still gives the same error somehow. what should I do?

Comment: I would start by looking in the Windows Event Viewer for error messages from MYSQL

Comment: Also that `Path to Executable" looks odd. I would Uninstall MySQL and start the install again making sure you run it using an Administrator Account

Comment: @RiggsFolly how would windows even viewer help?

Comment: _how would windows event viewer help_ MYSQL log errors into the Event Log Before it opens its own text logs. So if you look at the Event Viewer **You may see what the probelm is because you may see an error message**

Comment: @nbk i tried to start it manually form services but it's no help

Comment: repeat it, the service takes to long to respond on Windows 10 1903. Like i said a stupid bug. Once it is running no problem even with computer restart

Comment: @nbk it gives the sem error msg in 8.0.17 which i installed previously. But i installed it before that and it was working fine. I uninstalled it because wampserver was not working fine with it. Now i can't install this as well.

Comment: i tried it several times until it started. that was the first time i thought about using docker instead.

Comment: @nbk i only want to use MySQL for creating small databases n for learning purposes so docker can't relate.

Comment: a mysql docker with the data directory outside of the container, work like an installein server, because even after restart the datadirectory is still sthere and doesn't geht resettet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, **Error 2** in MySQL simply arises due to **missing file or wrong location**. Probably the path of the service you are trying to run is wrong or missing.

---

### Here are some reference of the same problem

- [windows could not start the MySQL. service on local computer. Error 2 : The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932056/windows-could-not-start-the-mysql-service-on-local-computer-error-2-the-syst)
- [MySql service Error 2: the system cannot find the file specified](https://thoughtscroll.wordpress.com/2007/06/21/mysql-service-error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified/)
- [Could not start the MySQL service on Local Computer. Error 2 [FIXED]](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,31448,31798#msg-31798)
- [the MySQL service on local computer started and then stopped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35670755/the-mysql-service-on-local-computer-started-and-then-stopped) *(Can also give this a look)*

  ---

### Possible Solution:

Check if the path to the service MySQL80 is proper and all the files exists with proper **execution and network permissions.** If nothing works, you can always use a **different version** to see if it is working there and if it does, **report a bug** in the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.Here's how I resolved it.

1. Win+R
2. input"services.msc", then click "Enter"
3. find the MySQL service, right click, choose the "attribute" option
4. choose the "log in" option, then choose "Local System Account"
   END
   I hope that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know,if we have the same Mysql program design,i'am using  the latest version 8.0.26.Try this:
Open your sql editor->go to navigator part left of the screen ->Inside -Instance- select *Startup/Shutdown* .

Then click on -Start server -button.

If didn't work ,or the program  was crashed, go to windows search tool and type -Services- then search about  Mysql service ,then click -start- it should be closed....

Hope this work..

Comment: Check also to confirm that the port is available or not used by another service

Answer (score 0):

Go to "C:\ProgramData\MySQL". You'll find a list of archived my.ini files.
Use one to replace the current my.ini file located inside "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server xx.0"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).